# Superscript on complexity class?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, oracle-machines

What does it mean when one complexity class has another complexity class superscript?

For example, sometimes in papers I see $P^P$ or $P^{NP}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a synthetic notation for complexity classes of oracle machines. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a class and $L$ be a language. We define:

$$
\mathcal{A}^L
$$

to be the complexity class of the languages decidable by a machine in class $\mathcal{A}$ with access to an oracle for $L$.

If $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are classes, we define:

$$
\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{L \in \mathcal{B}} \mathcal{A}^L
$$

Therefore, $\mathcal{P}^\mathcal{P}$ is the class of languages decidable in polynomial time by a machine with an oracle for any language of $\mathcal{P}$, and $\mathcal{P}^\mathcal{NP}$ is the class of languages decidable in polynomial time by a machine with an oracle for any language of $\mathcal{NP}$.

Answer (score 2):

That's referring to a complexity class defined in terms of [oracle machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine).  See the Wikipedia article on that topic for more.

For example, $P^L$ means the class of all problems that can be solved in polynomial time using a machine that has an oracle for $L$ (essentially, a subroutine you can invoke that magically tells you in $O(1)$ time whether $x \in L$ for any $x$ of your choice).  Also, $P^P$ means the union of $P^L$ over all $L \in P$, i.e., all problems that can be solved in polynomial time using a machine that has an oracle for any language in $P$ of your choice.